# Get variable value based on division of two integers

Tags: c#

I have to get the count of messages if the length of total message exceeds certain characters.

For Example - English character limit is 160 and Arabic is 70. If English message length is <=160 then count of variable should be 1 else between 161 -320 then the count of variable should be 2 and so on . Same in the case of Arabic if the message length is <=70 then count of variable should be 1 else between 71-140 then the count of variable should be 2 and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I was splitting the message this way
for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i += chunkSize)
                            {
                                if (i + chunkSize > stringLength)
                                {
                                    chunkSize = stringLength - i;
                                }
                            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question does not seem to be about c# but anyways. You should use `Math.Ceiling`

```
Console.Write(Math.Ceiling((double)161 / 160));
```

this code will return you 2 as you want.

Comment: Exactly this. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional statements like IF-ElseIf-Else or Switch case statement.

For example,

```
    string data="language data";
    char lanType='E';
    int len=data.Length("Your language character length");
    if(lanType='E')
    {
    if(len<=160)
    {
    //your logic
    }
else if(len>160 && len<=320)
{}
    //Rest of English language continuation
    }
    else if(lanType='A')
    {
    if(len<=160)
    {
    //your logic
    }
    //Rest of Arabic language continuation
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for this

```
const byte CHARLIMIT_EN = 160;
const byte CHARLIMIT_AR = 70;
var Count = Math.Ceil((double)text.Length / CHARLIMIT_EN);
// 0/160 => 0
// 1/160 => 1
// 160/160 => 1
// 161/160 => 2
```

Comment: Yes , some other user mentioned the same. Thank you for the inputs